# How to reload or refresh only child component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7, angular8

I have two components, One parent and Other Child.

HTML Part

```
<div>
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <!-- Some HTML Code of Parent component over here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
 </div>
 <button class="button" (click)="reloadOnlyChild($event)">Reload Child</button>
</div>
```

Now, On click of this button, I want the only child to get reload, or refresh.

TS Part

```
reloadOnlyChild(event){
  // I want to reload the child from here.
}
```

I searched on the Internet, I am getting for Vue or React, But not for Angular.

Comment: What do you mean by "reload" ? Have the *ngOnInit launch again ?

Comment: Suppose, Child component consists is a form.
I have filled that form.
I on button click, I am saving data, And I want it to reload So that all fields of that form become Empty and untouched.

Comment: Can you post more code or better create a stackblitz about this.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Best way to **update a child component** is: **ngOnChanges()**

**ngOnChanges():** "A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. Define an ngOnChanges() method to handle the changes." We use this lifecycle hook to respond to changes to our @Input() variables.

**Example:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "child-component",
  templateUrl: "./child-component.html"
})
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() someInput: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges() {
  /**********THIS FUNCTION WILL TRIGGER WHEN PARENT COMPONENT UPDATES 'someInput'**************/
  //Write your code here
   console.log(this.someInput);
  }   
 
}
```

**Use child component inside parent component as follows**

```
<child-component [someInput]="inputValue"></child-component>
```

Comment: this scenario will fail if you are deleing  with popup

Comment: Hey @ravipatel, no, it will not fail until you are not doing it right. What is the scenario you have?

Comment: I have a class which I pass to a child component, the class contains functions changing data inside itself, this is not change detected by Angular, So I simply added `@Input() lastChanged?: Date;` to the child and `lastChanged?: Date;` to the object which is updated locally inside functions. Pass it on to the child `<child [obj]="obj" [lastChanged]="obj.lastChanged" />` and the child's `ngOnChanges()` gets called.

Answer (score 31):

Say if you have a form in `Child.Component.ts` and if you want to reset it from `parent component` you can establish a connection between parent and child using `Subject`.

**Parent.Component.html**

```
<child-component [resetFormSubject]="resetFormSubject.asObservable()"></child-component>
<button (click)="resetChildForm()"></button>
```

**Parent.Component.ts**

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
resetFormSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

resetChildForm(){
   this.resetFormSubject.next(true);
}
```

**Child.Component.ts**

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
@Input() resetFormSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnInit(){
 this.resetFormSubject.subscribe(response => {
    if(response){
     yourForm.reset();
    // Or do whatever operations you need.
  }
 }
}
```

By using Subject you can establish a connection from parent to the child whenever the button gets clicked.

Hope this answer helps! Cheers :)

Answer (score 18):

You could add an Input to update the component, or add a update function in the child that you can call in the code. Using @ViewChild to call the child update function from the parent. Like this

( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-updatechild ):

Child:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
   selector: "app-child",
   templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
   styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"] 
})
export class ChildComponent {
   ticks = Date.now().valueOf();

   constructor() {}

   update(): void {
   this.ticks = Date.now().valueOf();
   }
}
```

Parent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ChildComponent } from "./../child/child.component";

@Component({
 selector: "app-parrent",
 templateUrl: "./parrent.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./parrent.component.css"]
})
export class ParrentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: false }) childC: ChildComponent;
  showChild: boolean = true;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onUpdateChild() {
    this.childC.update();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

We can also use `*ngIf` and `setTimeout` to reset the child component from parent without making any change in child component.

.template:

.ts:

```
show:boolean = true

resetChildForm(){
   this.show = false;

   setTimeout(() => {
      this.show = true
    }, 100);
}
```

This is particularly helpful when we have no control over child component, like a 3rd party library component.

Answer (score 6):

I used this approach and find it the easiest one. According to your code;

```
<!-- ParentComponent.html -->
<div>
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <!--- Observe; I added something here --->
    <child-component [someValueToGetChanges]="ValueInput"></child-component>
 </div>
</div>
```

And then use `ngOnChanges` `lifehook` of `angular` in our `childComponent`. `ngOnChanges` method is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. So in your `childComponent`, we'll do this;

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() 
  someValueToGetChanges: string;
  
  // this code is called when "someValueToGetChanges" value is changed by "ParentComponent"
  ngOnChanges() {
      // Code here what you want
      console.log(this.someValueToGetChanges);
  }   
  
  constructor() {}
}
```

Hope, it'll work for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

Suhas Parameshwara's answer is nice, but it's missing an unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks which might catch someone out who is copy pasting the solution. There's also a redundant Subject creation (it's also an Observable, not a Subject) which hides an error when you try to subscribe if you forget to pass in an Observable to the child.

Here's a more complete solution:

**Parent.Component.html**

```html
<child-component [resetForm]="formResetter.asObservable()"></child-component>
<button (click)="resetChildForm()"></button>
```

**Parent.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
})
export class ParentClass {

  public formResetter: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  resetChildForm() {
    this.formResetter.next(true);
 }
}
```

**Child.Component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
})
export class ChildClass implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() resetForm: Observable<boolean>;

  private sub: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.resetForm.subscribe(response => {
    // do whatever operations you need.
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.ngUnsubscribe();
  }
}
```